# Field Length validation - Agile toolkit

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

In a model User I have this field.

```
 $this->addField('login')->mandatory(true)->caption('Login')->length(10);
```

But when I enter text longer than 10 characters, the validation never occurs, and never shows the red message below the field saying: "text too long"

How can I do this in agile toolkit 4.2.4?? I miss something basic???

Thanks in advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in Field class length() method description:

```
 This will provide a HTML settings on a field for maximum field size.
 The length of a field will not be enforced by this setting.
 ...
```

Field->length($n) doesn't do any validation itself. It's just there for form field display purposes and also you can use this value somewhere in your own validation class something like this:

```
// In model class file init method
$model->addHook('beforeSave', array($this, 'customValidation'));

// In model class file
function customValidation() {
    foreach ($this->getActualFields() as $f) {
        $field = $this->getField($f);
        if ($field->length && strlen($this[$f]) > $field->length) {
            throw $this->exception('Field value to long', 'Exception_ValidityCheck')
                ->addMoreInfo('field', $f)
                ->addMoreInfo('value', $this[$f])
                ->addMoreInfo('limit', $field->length);
        }
    }
}
```

Code above is completely untested - just to give you idea. You can also validate field value length on Form submit hook, but that's not exactly correct. Better is to do this in Model.

Also check out validation add-on made by Romans https://github.com/romaninsh/validation. It's has to be very powerful.

Comment: The addon looks good!! 
Also your spinnet, it could be good for the framework to have buit-in some kind of validation like this ;)
many thanks mate!

Comment: At start we worked together with Romans on idea of this validation add-on, but final author of add-on is Romans :) Idea was to implement this add-on in ATK core in next major ATK release, but maybe that add-on will be left out of ATK core (to keep it light) and be available as separate, and I guess very popular, add-on which is almost the same as in core. And yes, you're more than welcome. Please accept my answer if it's acceptable by you :)

Comment: Best explanation at the moment for sure mate!